# Data types with same field names

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble making bigger programs in Haskell and one problem is the ambiguous error that occurs when I define data types with the same or matching field names.

```
data Board  = Board  { width :: Int, height :: Int }
data Player = Player { strength :: Int, width :: Int, height :: Int }
```

I am comfortable with writing small programs but when I find this issue, I run away and desperate.

In other languages I could just do:

```
board.width  = 100;
board.height = 100;

player.width = 5;
player.height = 2;
```

I find that I could prefix each field name with the type name (i.e boardWith, playerWidth) but is this the best approach and good practice? What should I do?

Comment: well yes you can do this - or you can but those into different modules and qualify the names through it

Comment: There are three basic options. (1) make type-specific names, such as your `boardWidth` and `playerWidth` suggestion. (2) Put each data type definition into its own separate module, so that when it is imported, it will be accessed as you describe (e.g. `Board.width`), or (3) create a type class like `HasWidth` that requires a type to implement a `width` function to belong to the type class, then make each of `Board` and `Player` an instance of the `HasWidth` type class with appropriate implementations -- behind the scenes Haskell will dispatch a call to the generic `width` for the right types.

Comment: I know it's probably not a xy problem but in your case shouldn't you embbed a board in a player ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the fields unique prefixes is a valid approach. This is a known somewhat-problem in Haskell, and there are several ways to work around that.

One of the most sophisticated solutions is [vinyl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl), which basically implements a new record system (or several, depending how you look at it) - allowing you to share fields between records, and even provides a notion of 'subtyping'. Depending on how familiar with Haskell you are, it might no necessarily be easy to use though. You should definitely check it out though.

Comment: `lens` is also a good solution, as it allows to generate lenses working for different types using either `makeFieilds` or `makeClassy` (I personally like `makeClassy` lots.

Comment: @mb14 Vinyl provides lenses for its record fields, so I wouldn't necessarily view them as separate things. Lens makes working with vinyl a lot easier.

Comment: I find this too overkill. Prefixing or creating modules seems the best approach so far.

Comment: @catgocat whether or not it's overkill really depends on what you want to do with it in the end

Answer (score 0):

One option is to keep your data types as they are and make some functions like:

```hs
data Board  = Board  { width :: Int, height :: Int }

boardWidth :: Board -> Int
boardWidth (Board w _) = w
```